# Why Youtube video is not showing in Webview in react native mobile app?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to show youtube video in Webview for ios mobile app in react native but it throws me an error like ,   :  Error Loading Page -1200 as shown in photo.[image]

Youtbe Videos not working in Web view.

here is the code

```
                      <WebView
                            style={{flex:1}}
                            javaScriptEnabled={true}
                            source={{uri: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/q-JCoQ_lI58'}}
                    />
```

[image]

My Network Security in Info.plist is shown in photo.